Orbeon Forms: How to move down to next question
Some of our forms have 10-20 questions, and when answer the question at the bottom of the current page, the user has to page-down to see the next question, and so on until they reach the last question..
Is there a way to set the focus of the next question once the previous question has been answered?
Many thanks in advance
PeteA

When users answer the current question, they can press Tab to move to the next one, which will bring the corresponding field into focus. Or are you thinking of a different use case? Perhaps specifically radio buttons for forms completed on a mobile device?

Some of our forms are quite long and have many questions. And the next question is not displayed until the previous question has been answered. The issue with this is that when the next question is displayed it is off the bottom of the screen and the user is constantly paging down. It would be more convenient for the user if the next question is brought into view when the previous question has been answered.
PeteA

Are you using the visibility formula to display the questions? For instance, for the visibility of q5, would you use a condition like $q4 != ''? If so, I assume that none of the questions are in the form of a text field or text area?

Yes, subsequent fields are hidden (by a visibility condition formula) until the previous question has been answered.

Here is a prototype demonstrating the behavior (to best observe the scrolling effect, try making your browser window shorter): https://html-preview.github.io/?url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/avernet/800b7c3fdf6e2258fb0a4e4caef87d61/raw/965f70ac8288e7c00818eba9d00b4bbe4eb38327/autoscroll-on-height-change.html
Is this the behavior you're looking for? If so, you can incorporate the code into your form. The code is generic and can be found at the bottom of https://gist.github.com/avernet/800b7c3fdf6e2258fb0a4e4caef87d61.

Hi Alex - this is exactly what we're looking for.
I thought I saw that 